# Javascript injection goes wrong

Tags: android-webview

In our `Android` project (download manager) we need to show built-in web browser so we able to catch downloads there with the all data (headers, cookies, post data) so we can handle them properly.

Unfortunately, `WebView` control we use does not provide any way to access `POST` data of the requests it makes.
So we use a hacky way to get this data. We inject this `javascript` code in the each `html` code the browser loads:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = formSubmitMonitor;

    window.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        formSubmitMonitor(e);
    }, true);

    function formSubmitMonitor(e) {
        var frm = e ? e.target : this;
        formSubmitMonitor_onsubmit(frm);
        frm._submit();
    }

    function formSubmitMonitor_onsubmit(f) {
        var data = "";
        for (i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++) {
            var name = f.elements[i].name;
            var value = f.elements[i].value;
            //var type = f.elements[i].type;
            if (name)
            {
                if (data !== "")
                   data += '&';
                data += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
            }
        }

        postDataMonitor.onBeforeSendPostData(
                f.attributes['method'] === undefined ? null : f.attributes['method'].nodeValue,
                new URL(f.action, document.baseURI).href,
                data,
                f.attributes['enctype'] === undefined ? null : f.attributes['enctype'].nodeValue);
    }

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        // these will be the key to retrieve the payload
        this.recordedMethod = method;
        this.recordedUrl = url;
        this.origOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
    };

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
        if (body)
        {
            postDataMonitor.onBeforeSendPostData(
                this.recordedMethod,
                this.recordedUrl,
                body,
                null);
        }
        this.origSend(body);
    };

    const origFetch = window.fetch;
    window.fetch = function()
    {
        postDataMonitor.onBeforeSendPostData(
                "POST",
                "test",
                "TEST",
                null);
        return origFetch.apply(this, arguments);
    }

</script>
```

Generally, it works fine.

But in Google Mail web interface, it's not working for some unknown reason. E.g. when the user enters his login name and presses `Next`. I thought it's using `Fetch API`, so I've added interception for it too. But this did not help. Please note, that we do not need to intercept the user credentials, but we need to be able to intercept all, or nothing. Unfortunately, this is the way the whole system works there...

**Addition #1.**
I've found another way: don't override `shouldInterceptRequest`, but override `onPageStarted` instead and call `evaluateJavascript` there. That way it works even on Google Mail web site! But why the first method is not working then? We break HTML code somehow?